# Set property of a class in a destination controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to set a property of a class instantiated in a destination segue.

Specifically, I have a root view controller with a button on it.  The button is just a segue to another view controller via the storyboard.  In prepareForSegue, I instantiate the destination view controller, then set a property.

When the property is a simple object (int, NSInt, NSString, etc.) of the destination, then the assignment works - i.e. I can NSLog before and after the assignment and see the value change from zero to the number I assigned.

However, when the property is an instance of a simple class I've created, there is no compile or runtime error, but the value remains zero.

Things I've tried:

My understanding is @synthesize is done automatically, but I tried anyway.

I tried putting the properties in the class header interface as well, but I don't think that's needed either.

I also built a new project with the code below to make sure it wasn't just something weird as it was part of a much larger app.  I excluded the delegate for the backward segue since it's working fine.

I've found lots of examples of passing data forward but I couldn't find anything with a class as I need.

Given the lack of errors, this feels like a scope or initialization problem, but after 3 days of fumbling I'm out of ideas.

//  menuViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Settings.h"
#import "setupViewController.h"

@interface menuViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

//  menuViewController.m

```
#import "menuViewController.h"

@interface menuViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

@end

@implementation menuViewController {
Settings *menuSettings;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSecond"]) {
        setupViewController *instanceOfSetupViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        // This assign doesn't change the property in the destination
        instanceOfSetupViewController.myLocalSettings.bpm = 67;

        // This local assign works
        menuSettings.bpm = 77;
        // But this assign doesn't change the property in the destination
        instanceOfSetupViewController.myLocalSettings = menuSettings;
    }
}

- (IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {}
```

//  setupViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Settings.h"

@interface setupViewController : UIViewController

@property () Settings* myLocalSettings;
@end
```

//  setupViewController.m

```
#import "setupViewController.h"

@interface setupViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

@end

@implementation setupViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Settings *myLocalSettings = [[Settings alloc] init];
    myLocalSettings.bpm = 13;
}

- (IBAction)myButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromSecond" sender:self];
}
```

//  Settings.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Settings : NSObject

@property () NSInteger bpm;
@end
```

//  Settings.m

```
#import "Settings.h"
@implementation Settings
@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you haven't yet created a Settings object, so myLocalSettings is nil. At the time prepareForSegue is called, the destination view controller's view has not been loaded, so the Settings object you instantiate in viewDidLoad won't have been created yet (you should delete that one, or it will overwrite the one you create here). You should create that instance first in prepareForSegue,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSecond"]) {
        setupViewController *instanceOfSetupViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        instanceOfSetupViewController.myLocalSettings = [Settings new];
        instanceOfSetupViewController.myLocalSettings.bpm = 67;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating the object solved my problem.

  But while your suggestion/explanation to remove it from viewDidLoad makes sense, I could not get that work.
  If I comment it out, then I just get 'Use of undeclared identifier'.

Comment: I tried "Settings *myLocalSettings;" instead, but then assignments in setup exhibit the same behavior I had in menu - the values remain zero.  Then I tried #import "menuViewController.m", hoping that would let the compiler realize it was defined elsewhere, but it still says undeclared.

Comment: @Greg What code are you trying that results in getting the undeclared identifier error? Did you leave in the line, `myLocalSettings.bpm = 13;`?

Comment: In setupViewController.m, when I comment out  ""Settings *myLocalSettings = [[Settings alloc] init];", then the next line 
"myLocalSettings.bpm = 13;" says "Use of undeclared identifier 'myLocalSetting'.  I think that's what you meant when you say to "delete that one".

Comment: @Greg myLocalSettings is a property, so you should refer to it as self.myLocalSetting from within the setupViewController -- what you were doing previously with, `Settings *myLocalSettings = [[Settings alloc] init];` was creating a local variable called myLocalSettings. Anyway, it makes no sense to set it to 13 because that will just overwrite the value you passed in from prepareForSegue.

Comment: I am trying to pass a class to the setup controller, allow the user to change the settings in that class, and pass it back.  Adding "self." before accessing myLocalSettings cleared the compile errors, however it still acts like it isn't initialized.  It is always zero when accessed from setupVC so the value being set in the menu VC and the local 13 (which is just a test) aren't saved.

Comment: @Greg I don't know what you mean by "I am trying to pass a class to the setup controller". What class are you trying to pass, and what does that have to do with the question you asked? There's nothing in your posted code that passes a class.

Comment: You're correct.  I did not mention that, but I do want to pass the entire Settings class rather than just the bpm property.  I was just taking baby steps.

Comment: @Greg It doesn't really make sense to pass a class. Any class can access any other class (as long as it imports the header), there's no need to pass it. I think you need to edit your question to make it more clear what you're trying to accomplish, and what code you're using now that still isn't working.

Comment: OK, I've got it working in my actual app.  Thank you!  As far as passing a class, I meant passing an instance of a class.